# How to add inline style to React component as prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to move the BUTTON component below by adding a style further up my screen but it does not seem to be responding.

```
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({

downButton: {
marginLeft: 10,
bottom: 50
},
}));

function App() {
const style = useStyles();

  <Button
  style={useStyles.downButton}
  onClick={() => console.log('clicked')}
  color="default"
  startIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon/>}
  ></Button>

  }
```

How do I add style this button and move it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `style` not `useStyles` when you call css in component:

```
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({

downButton: {
marginLeft: 10,
bottom: 50
},
}));

function App() {
const style = useStyles();

  <Button
  className={style.downButton} //<-- here should be style, not useStyles
  onClick={() => console.log('clicked')}
  color="default"
  startIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon/>}
  ></Button>

  }
```

Comment: I seem to get an error after chaning styles to style

Error: The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX.

Comment: @MoMiah try to replace `style` prop with `className`. I updated my answer

Comment: @MoMiah No problem. If you think the answer is correct, please, mark it as valid. Happy coding =)

Answer (score 1):

You was almost there

```
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({

downButton: {
marginLeft: 10,
bottom: 50
},
}));

function App() {
const style = useStyles(); 

  <Button
  style={style.downButton} //THIS SHOULD BE style NOT useStyles
  onClick={() => console.log('clicked')}
  color="default"
  startIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon/>}
  ></Button>

  }
```

Comment: Error: The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX.